# Monotouch check the current platform

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I am trying to figure how can i find the current device **platform**.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the Answer in [the Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889695/how-do-i-get-the-ios-device-and-version-in-monotouch/10889966#10889966) and For Easy access i m also posting that codes Here.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Playersync_iPhone_v2 {
public class DeviceHardware {
    public const string HardwareProperty = "hw.machine";

    public enum HardwareVersion {
        iPhone,
        iPhone3G,
        iPhone3GS,
        iPhone4,
        VerizoniPhone4,
        iPhone4S,
        iPod1G,
        iPod2G,
        iPod3G,
        iPod4G,
        iPad,
        iPad2WIFI,
        iPad2WIFI24,
        iPad2GSM,
        iPad2CDMA,
        iPad3WIFI,
        iPad3GSM,
        iPad3CDMA,
        iPhoneSimulator,
        iPhone4Simulator,
        iPadSimulator,
        Unknown
    }

    [DllImport(MonoTouch.Constants.SystemLibrary)]
    static internal extern int sysctlbyname([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string property, IntPtr output, IntPtr oldLen, IntPtr newp, uint newlen);

    public static HardwareVersion Version {
        get {
            var pLen = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));
            sysctlbyname(DeviceHardware.HardwareProperty, IntPtr.Zero, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

            var length = Marshal.ReadInt32(pLen);

            if (length == 0) {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pLen);

                return HardwareVersion.Unknown;
            }

            var pStr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
            sysctlbyname(DeviceHardware.HardwareProperty, pStr, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

            var hardwareStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pStr);
            var ret = HardwareVersion.Unknown;



            if (hardwareStr == "iPhone1,1")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPhone1,2")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone3G;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPhone2,1")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone3GS;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPhone3,1")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone4;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPhone3,3")
                ret = HardwareVersion.VerizoniPhone4;
            else if(hardwareStr == "iPhone4,1")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone4S;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPad1,1")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPad;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPad2,1")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPad2WIFI;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPad2,2")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPad2GSM;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPad2,3")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPad2CDMA;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPad2,4")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPad2WIFI24;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPad3,1")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPad3WIFI;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPad3,2")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPad3GSM;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPad3,3")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPad3CDMA;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPod1,1")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPod1G;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPod2,1")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPod2G;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPod3,1")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPod3G;
            else if (hardwareStr == "iPod4,1")
                ret = HardwareVersion.iPod4G;
            else if (hardwareStr == "i386" || hardwareStr=="x86_64") {
                if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Model.Contains("iPhone"))
                    ret = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height * UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 960 || UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width * UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 960 ? HardwareVersion.iPhone4Simulator : HardwareVersion.iPhoneSimulator;
                else
                    ret = HardwareVersion.iPadSimulator;
            }

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pLen);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pStr);

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I m not Duplicating You i m navigating to another answer see the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889695/how-do-i-get-the-ios-device-and-version-in-monotouch/10889966#10889966

Comment: You edited the question after my comment. You also don't quote your original source.

Comment: If i could have edited the answer There it should be mentioned Like **Edited : sometimes Before** by someone (Check Properly ). It was a destiny that we given the same answer from the same Link With in Some minutes difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet I found from a quick Google search. Should be trivial to update for the latest round of hardware.

Source: http://www.bscheiman.org/2010/08/30/detecting-hardware-type-monotouch/

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class DeviceHardware
    {
        public const string HardwareProperty = "hw.machine";

        public enum HardwareVersion
        {
            iPhone,
            iPhone3G,
            iPhone3GS,
            iPhone4,
            iPod1G,
            iPod2G,
            iPod3G,
            iPad,
            iPhoneSimulator,
            iPhone4Simulator,
            iPadSimulator,
            Unknown
        }

        [DllImport(MonoTouch.Constants.SystemLibrary)]
        static internal extern int sysctlbyname([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string property, IntPtr output, IntPtr oldLen, IntPtr newp, uint newlen);

        public static HardwareVersion Version
        {
            get
            {
                var pLen = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));
                sysctlbyname(DeviceHardware.HardwareProperty, IntPtr.Zero, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

                var length = Marshal.ReadInt32(pLen);

                if (length == 0)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pLen);

                    return HardwareVersion.Unknown;
                }

                var pStr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
                sysctlbyname(DeviceHardware.HardwareProperty, pStr, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

                var hardwareStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pStr);
                var ret = HardwareVersion.Unknown;

                if (hardwareStr == "iPhone1,1")
                    ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone;
                else if (hardwareStr == "iPhone1,2")
                    ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone3G;
                else if (hardwareStr == "iPhone2,1")
                    ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone3GS;
                else if (hardwareStr == "iPhone3,1")
                    ret = HardwareVersion.iPhone4;
                else if (hardwareStr == "iPad1,1")
                    ret = HardwareVersion.iPad;
                else if (hardwareStr == "iPod1,1")
                    ret = HardwareVersion.iPod1G;
                else if (hardwareStr == "iPod2,1")
                    ret = HardwareVersion.iPod2G;
                else if (hardwareStr == "iPod3,1")
                    ret = HardwareVersion.iPod3G;
                else if (hardwareStr == "i386")
                {
                    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Model.Contains("iPhone"))
                        ret = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height * UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 960 || UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width * UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 960 ? HardwareVersion.iPhone4Simulator : HardwareVersion.iPhoneSimulator;
                    else
                        ret = HardwareVersion.iPadSimulator;
                }

                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pLen);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pStr);

                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Should be trivial to update for the latest round of hardware."