# Monotouch - Layout Table View Cell where a group of buttons align right

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, interface-builder

I have a table view cell with a label to the left and three buttons to the right. I want the buttons to stick to the right of the cell when the UI is on an iPad - atm it looks like they are set for iPhone. I'm new to the new xCode UI and have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You may be best off setting the position based on the device at runtime.

Here is a snippit in raw objective C: https://gist.github.com/1323251

Also, here is a snippit for use in monotouch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10889966/1948968